# Json data ordering PANDAS, python

Tags: python, pandas

I have json like this:

```
json = {
 "b": 22,
 "x": 12,
 "a": 2,
 "c": 4
}
```

When i generate an Excel file from this `json` like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json(json_text)
file_name = 'test.xls'
file_path = "/tmp/" + file_name
df.to_excel(file_path, index=False)

print("path to excel " + file_path)
```

Pandas does its own ordering in the Excel file like this:

```
pandas_json = {
"a": 2,
"b": 22,
"c": 4,
"x": 12
}
```

I don't want this. I need the ordering which exists in the `json`. Please give me some advice how to do this.

UPDATE: 
if i have json like this:

```
json = [
{"b": 22, "x":12, "a": 2, "c": 4},
{"b": 22, "x":12, "a": 2, "c": 2},
{"b": 22, "x":12, "a": 4, "c": 4},
]
```

pandas will generate its own ordering like this:

```
panas_json = [
{"a": 2, "b":22, "c": 4, "x": 12},
{"a": 2, "b":22, "c": 2, "x": 12},
{"a": 4, "b":22, "c": 4, "x": 12},
]
```

How can I make pandas preserve my own ordering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the json as `OrderedDict` which will help to retain original order:

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict

json_ = """{
"b": 22,
"x": 12,
"a": 2,
"c": 4
}"""

data = json.loads(json_, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data,orient='index')
```

---

```
    0
b  22
x  12
a   2
c   4
```

Edit, updated json also works:

```
j="""[{"b": 22, "x":12, "a": 2, "c": 4},
{"b": 22, "x":12, "a": 2, "c": 2},{"b": 22, "x":12, "a": 4, "c": 4}]"""
```

---

```
data = json.loads(j, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data).to_json(orient='records')
```

---

```
'[{"b":22,"x":12,"a":2,"c":4},{"b":22,"x":12,"a":2,"c":2}, 
  {"b":22,"x":12,"a":4,"c":4}]'
```

Comment: Thanks! can you look at the more complex jason? I have updated my question